# How to get Related fields in conga composer

Tags: salesforce

I have installed conga composer 8 and created button in Opportunities tab but when I open Conga ,related fields are not showing in any tab. So how do I get the related fields or where can I find it ?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest method to gather information from related objects for use with Conga Composer is to incorporate a report and/or query to your Composer Solution.  Conga Composer allows you to gather this information in a highly customized manner.  Here's a great set of articles from the Conga support site on how to incorporate information from related (or parent) objects.

[Gathering Data for Composer](https://support.getconga.com/Conga_Composer/Composer_Essentials/Gathering_Data_for_Composer)

Considerations

1. If you are currently (or plan to) use Lightning, Queries are the recommended method because of some limitations around Report Export in Lightning
2. Queries give you more flexibility in the data gathered and can support aggregated and advanced filtering: [Using SOQL Queries with Conga Composer](https://support.getconga.com/Conga_Composer/Composer_Essentials/Gathering_Data_for_Composer/10_Using_SOQL_Queries_with_Conga_Composer)

If you get stuck, never hesitate to throw a case over to our support team for assistance